# Subscript in the title of a reference within the bibliography list

Tags: overleaf, subscripts, mendeley

I would like to know if it is possible to add a subscript to the title of a reference in the bibliography list. Please find the example below for clarification.

Mechanism of protective film formation during CO2 corrosion of carbon steel

The 2 in the CO2 needs to be subscript. Please note that I am using Mendeley to import the bibliography list to Overleaf.

Regards,
LS

Comment: You can use (most) normal LaTeX syntax in your bibliography titles, like `title = {film formation during $\mathrm{CO_2}$ corrosion}` or something similar (probably you are using a package like `mhchem` or `chemformula` to display molecule names in the text, you can use that as well in the bibliography). I'm not sure how Mendeley export works, probably you need to set some option to export 'raw' text, otherwise maybe Mendeley will try to escape backslashes and brackets etc.

Comment: Thank you Marijn, I am using \usepackage{natbib} to import the bibliography from Mendeley, where I have the option to escape symbols in Latex. Unfortunately, nothing seems to work in the bibliography.

Comment: The idea is that you _don't_ escape special characters, you want to keep them to make subscripts etc. In any case, if you cannot get the Mendeley export to work, then you can always edit the exported `.bib` file yourself afterwards to add the subscripts. To help you further it would be best if you can show the complete entry from the `.bib` file and the complete code for a small document that cites this entry.

Comment: Marijn, I cannot thank you enough for this suggestion. I went with manually modifying individual references.